# Texas Instrument Launchpad MSP-EXP430G2 tactile switch / push button power specifications and manufacturer number

Tags: launchpad

What are the current and voltage maximum and minimum limits for the push buttons / tactile switches  on the TI Launchpad  MSP-EXP430G2 ?
Also, what is the manufacturer number for this component ?  I have not found any datasheet that details this information.

Comment: Look at the eval board BOM

Comment: thanks for the post.  that was the first thing i did using the texas instrument user's guide for this launchpad, with literature number: SLAU318F.   the BOM in this document (page 23) does not list the manufacturer numbers of the components in the circuit  for some reason, nor does it list  the minimum and maximum  limits of each component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.ti.com/tool/download/SLAC437 on the TI website contains a link to download the MSP-EXP430G2 Hardware Design Files.

Inside the download there is a MSP-EXP430G2_LaunchPad_BOM.xls spreadsheet containing the Bill Of Materials (BOM) for the launchpad. This has the row with:

| Pos. | Ref Des | Number per board | Description | DigiKey part # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43 | S1, S2 | 2 | Push Button | P12225STB-ND |

[P12225STB-ND](https://www.digikey.be/en/products/detail/panasonic-electronic-components/EVQ-21505R/160362) is the DigiKey page the switch part number.

The switch is `EVQ-21505R` manufactured by *Panasonic Electronic Components*. The description is:

> SWITCH TACTILE SPST-NO 0.02A 15V

The EVQ-21505R is reported as obsolete, and can't seem to find the datasheet on the Panasonic website.

[Light Touch Switches/EVQ2](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/315/PANAS38662_1-2560512.pdf) is the datasheet found on the Mouser website and lists following electrical parameters:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer.  i reviewed the info you posted.  it  is  pretty close  to  what i was  looking for.  that information must be for a different version of the same type of launchpad.  it is remarkable how much information there is pertaining to different versions of the same  or similar model numbers.  

following your logic,  i found this link:  http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-exp430g2.   it also leads to  hardware design files.  i  found this link  from  the  user's guide with literature number:  SLAU318F.   it  appears to match the  specs  i was looking for:  50 mA  at  12VDC.

Comment: @keikaku Do you have the [MSP-EXP430G2ET](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430G2ET) launchpad, which is a later version of the MSP-EXP430G2?

Comment: no,  i  do not. i only have the MSP-EXP430G2, based on what is written on the box, the invoice, and the board.  for some reason,  the user guide pdf i mentioned has that link written  in it on page 4.  btw,  the  user guide  is  entitled "MSP-EXP430G2  Launchpad Evaluation Kit  User's Guide".  Texas  Instruments.       so  there is clear inconsistency in the labeling of the info being provided.  your  opinion ??  should  i  answer my own question and list this as the answer ?

Comment: @keikaku http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-exp430g2 on the TI website now redirects to https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430G2ET, which is for the later version of the launchpad. https://web.archive.org/web/20160315014538/http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-exp430g2 is an old archived version of the TI webpage for the MSP-EXP430G2, which is where I found the link to download the MSP-EXP430G2 Hardware Design Files.

Comment: is the info that i found  reliable  in your view ?   this is the part number i  found through that link in the hardware files:  1188E-1K2-V-TR.  Diptronics  is  the manufacturer.  And it is available from  Mouser.  it  sounds  like this  switch rated for  20 mA  at  15 VDC  would work just as well as a switch rated for 50 mA at  12 VDC  for  such a low power  MCU  ??

Comment: @keikaku Can you edit the question to include a picture of the launchpad and highlight switch you are asking about.

Comment: here is a link to an image of the board i have.  i  do not know how to just upload from my laptop into  this  site.   the  buttons  are  on the bottom:  P1.2  or  Reset.

 https://images.app.goo.gl/vHDHEttr1gsGDwQ2A

Comment: @keikaku The image shows the switches are the EVQ-21505R through-hole mounting parts I listed in the answer, for the MSP-EXP430G2. The 1188E-1K2-V-TR from the comments is surface mount side push type switch, used on the later generation MSP-EXP430G2ET launchpad.

Comment: where does the image  show  the EVQ-21505R  part  number ?  i  am not seeing that.

Comment: nevermind, i  looked up EVQ-21505R  on  the  Digikey site.  they have   alternative  switches.  i  appreciate all your  effort.